# Different .app name - new submission iPhone

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I have recently rewrote my application and started with a fresh project. The App its self is using the same bundle seed and Bundle identifier.

As my project has a slightly different name the app it produces a slightly differnet .app (file name) to what is already in the store.

Am i right in thinking as long as the bundle ID is the same i wont have any issues?

Thanks Ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple distinguish apps on the basis of bundle id (com.yourCompanyName.appName) so don't worry its OK.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to make an update to your app in the AppStore. Then you are thinking right. As long as you don't change the bundle id it is ok. You can't change the bundle id when you make an app update but the app name of course.